# How to generate random item from json file in yaml code for artilliery load testing?

Tags: yaml, load-testing, artillery

[Artilliery load testing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrxq3.png)

I want to use a random string(number) from numbers.json (it's an array of numbers not like usual json file) (number is denoted by 'from' in above mentioned code. click the link) for one complete flow. and also want to randomly select query from queries.json file. I want 4 iterations of these requests for each flow.

This randomItem doesn't work here. Can anyone fix this issue by providing some different method. Also mention if you find any other bug in this code.